# Can I use Collection.size() to replace the counter in this code?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Here's the code:

```
public class LogService {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private final LoggerThread loggerThread;
    private final PrintWriter writer;
    @GuardedBy("this") private boolean isShutdown;
    @GuardedBy("this") private int reservations;    //  <-- counter
    public void start() { loggerThread.start(); }
    public void stop() {
        synchronized (this) { isShutdown = true; }
        loggerThread.interrupt();
    }
    public void log(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (isShutdown)
                throw new IllegalStateException(...);
            ++reservations;
        }
        queue.put(msg);
    }
    private class LoggerThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (LogService.this) {
                            if (isShutdown && reservations == 0)
                                break;
                        }
                        String msg = queue.take();
                        synchronized (LogService.this) {
                            --reservations;
                        }
                        writer.println(msg);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* retry */ }
                }
            } finally {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a snippet from the book *Java Concurrency in Practice*, and I'm thinking about that maybe the counter `reservations` is unnecessary as we could simply use `queue.size()` to get the number of elements in `queue`.

Am I right?

Comment: queue `put` and `get` is not synchronized. `reservations` modification is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that would create a deadlock actually.

You would need to synchronize `put` and `take` if you want to use `size` in a parallel fashion. But `take` is blocking and you would now have a blocking `take` call synchronized on the same object as the `put` call. `take` can't take until something is `put`. `put` can't put until `take` gives up the lock. That's a deadlock.

Comment: I looked through the source code of `put` and `take` method, and it seems that they are synchronized with `Lock`.

Comment: @user2916610 the question would be if `size` is synchronized as well.

Comment: `size` is synchronized as well.

Comment: @user2916610 I'm looking at [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java#LinkedBlockingQueue.put%28java.lang.Object%29) and put/take use different locks.

Comment: As `put` uses a `Lock` while`size` does not, replace the counter with `queue.size()` could create a race condition. But I can't figure out in what cases there would be a deadlock.

Comment: @user2916610 I was assuming you would try to fix the race condition by putting `.size()` in the same lock as `put` and `take`. You could also have a race condition instead of a deadlock, and I think it's a race condition that can lead to a bug since logging will happen with delay and the last log message (you know the one that says why you're shutting down, for instance) won't be printed.

Comment: @djechlin, I'm looking into `ArrayBlockingQueue` and methods `put`, `take` and `size` use the same lock.

Answer (score 0):

Using "reservations" variable is good domain design because it is much more meaningful than size, you can use that to express domain concept like total number of reservation available etc

On the performance side

**ArrayBlockingQueue** -  calling size function will result in slowness because it acquires lock to read the size and that will slow down take or put operation also.

**LinkedBlockingQueue** - Calling size is atomic/volatile read and it has performance cost.